# Json Schema from Kafka Registry to Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have been developing a solution to ingest streaming data from Kafka topic into Databricks.

As part of this development, I have read the schema from Kafka registry. Read is successful and I am able to print the schema print(schema).

I was trying to load the streaming data using this schema and it throws error "AnalysisException: Cannot parse the schema in JSON format: Failed to convert the JSON string". I used below code for kafka ingestion

```
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").options(**options).load().select(col("value").cast("string")).select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("data"))

display(df)
```

So i thought it is parsing error so parsed the schema using code parsed_schema = json.loads(schema). parsing is successful and parsed_schema got created.

Again i tried to read the data from Kafka using this schema but again receiving another error "py4j.Py4JException: Method from_json([class org.apache.spark.sql.Column, class java.util.HashMap, class java.util.HashMap]) does not exist"

Code I used with updated schema is

```
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").options(**options).load().select(col("value").cast("string")).select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), parsed_schema).alias("data"))

display(df)
```

Could you please guide me how to apply the json schema from kafka registry. Thanks in advance

Comment: The `schema` needs to be a Spark Schema object, not a Python dict (`json.loads`) or string (HTTP registry response)

Comment: Thanks for quick response on this query. Could you please guide me how to convert it to schema object

Comment: In Python I'm not sure how to do it from JSON, I usually build it manually - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema

Comment: Thank you for support. Still I need to figure out way to convert json string to spark schema.

Comment: Create a `StructType` object like the link shows (from `parsed_schema`, or manually), then use `from_json` like you've already done. More examples here - https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/26/processing-data-in-apache-kafka-with-structured-streaming-in-apache-spark-2-2.html